# How to change the value of buttons undependable React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build a tic-tac-toe game using class to practice passing the props to child components and lifting up the state of component that's why you can see my creating 4 components.

The problem I need help with is so that when I click one of the buttons all buttons change their value at the same time.

I need to make each button display its own value separately. I declared a function and gave it functionality to change the state from null to X or O.

```
// App component 
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
 
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Board />
      </>
    );
  }
}

// Board component 
class Board extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {txt: 'X'};
    this.change = this.change.bind(this);
  }
  change(){
    const updt = (this.state.txt === 'X' || this.state.txt === '0') ? 'O' : 'X';
    this.setState({txt: updt}); 
  }
  render() {
    return(
       <>
        <div>
          <Row key={'1'} value={this.state.txt} change={this.change}/>
          <Row key={'2'} value={this.state.txt} change={this.change}/>
          <Row key={'3'} value={this.state.txt} change={this.change}/>
        </div>
      </>
    )
  }
}

// Box component 
function Box(props){
  return (
    <>
      <button  className='class1' onClick={props.change} >{props.value}</button>
    </>
  );
}

// Row component 
function Row(props){
    return (
      <>
        <div id='myId'>
          <Box change={props.change} value={props.value}/>
          <Box change={props.change} value={props.value}/>
          <Box change={props.change} value={props.value}/>
        </div>
      </>
    )
}


ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

Comment: If you need separate state for each button then you need to have separate state for each button. In a tic-tac-toe board each cell has its own state; I would start by figuring out what that state would look like.

Answer (score 0):

all of your button change text because you literally passing them the same value , instead you need to create an array of rows each row contains an array of buttons , and then you map over these array like I'm down down below , that's how things are meant to be don in react . I also added a user turn functionality .

```
// App component 
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
 
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Board />
      </>
    );
  }
}

// Board component 
class Board extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
turn:"X",

rows:[
//ROW 1 
         [
            {
            id:"btn1",
            text:"0"
            },
            {
            id:"btn2",
            text:"0"
            },
            {
            id:"btn3",
            text:"0"
            },
         ],
//ROW 2 
         [
            {
            id:"btn1",
           text:"0"
            },
            {
            id:"btn2",
            text:"0"
            },
            {
            id:"btn3",
            text:"0"
            },
         ],
//ROW 3 
         [
            {
            id:"btn1",
             text:"0"
            },
            {
            id:"btn2",
             text:"0"
            },
            {
            id:"btn3",
            text:"0"
            },
         ],
    ]};
    this.change = this.change.bind(this);
  }

  change(rowIndex,btnId,btnLastValue){
   
    const updt = (btnLastValue === 'X' || btnLastValue === '0') ? 'O' : 'X';
    let tempState= [...this.state.rows]
    const targetBtn= tempState[rowIndex].filter(btn=>btn.id==btnId)[0]
    const targetBtnIndex= tempState[rowIndex].indexOf(targetBtn)
    
    let updateText = this.state.turn=="X" ? "X": "O"
    const tempState[rowIndex][targetBtnIndex].text= updateText 
    
    this.setState({...this.state,rows: tempState, trun:updateText }); 
  }

  render() {
    return(
       <>
        <div>
          {
           this.state.rows.map((row,index)=><Row 
           key={index} 
           rowIndex={index} 
           row={row} 
           change={this.change}
           />
           )
          }
        </div>
      </>
    )
  }
}

// Box component 
function Box(props){
 const {value,rowIndex,change}=props
  return (
    <>
      <button  className='class1' onClick={e=>change(rowIndex,value.id,value.text)} >{props.value}</button>
    </>
  );
}

// Row component 
function Row(props){
    const {row,rowIndex,change}=props

    return (
      <>
        <div id='myId'>
           {
            rows.map(btn =><Box 
            change={change} 
            rowIndex={rowIndex} 
            value={btn}
            />)
            }  
        </div>
      </>
    )
}


ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector('#root'));
```